# IntelliJ: Scala Worksheet console removing leading spaces

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, format, space, worksheet

My problem is that leading spaces/blanks are removed from the beginning of their rows when I execute my Scala worksheet in IntelliJ. This code

```
    def test(a: Int, b: Int): Unit = {
  if(a != b){
    println((" " * a) + a)
    test(a+1, b)
  }
}

test(0, 10)
```

should return this

```
0
 1
  2
   3
    4
     ...
```

but does in fact just write the numbers on top of each other like this

```
0
1
2
3
4
...
```

Spaces/blanks at the end of strings are cut of as well, only the ones within remain, printing (" 1 2 3 4 ") results in ("1 2 3 4"). 
Let me know if you need logs or anything, I'm looking forward for help.

Comment: Bug report is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Comment: this is a bug report that a IntelliJ employee opened for me: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-14997, screenshots included

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

The same code is working fine for me, I guess the problem is with your Intellij version, I am using "2018.3.4" version.

Comment: That's not really an answer. More worthy of a comment. FWIW, it's not a version issue. I run 2018.3.4 and see the same removal of leading spaces. I suspect (but don't know) it might be an option hidden in the settings somewhere.

Comment: I've got the same version, even tried reinstalling the porgram. The code is working fine on my secondary computer with the same JDK/JRE and same IntelliJ, but it does not work (as intended) on the primary one.